# chrome 71 does not detect id in an onclick event unless it's this.id

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have an html element like this:

```
<select id="myselect" onclick="jsDoSomething(id)"><option>1</option><option>2</option></select>
```

Up to Chrome 70, everything worked fine and in Chrome 71, the `id` is null inside the `jsDoSomething` function. I have to alter it to `this.id` in order for it to work. Is this a bug or a ... feature of Chrome 71?

Thank you in advance.

Edit: this happens on both `select` and `a` tags but not on `button` tags.

Edit2: jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5L0djvqy/10/

Comment: I'm amazed it ever worked at all...

Comment: @Alnitak if it's a feature then why does it work on a button tag not on a select or a tag ?

Comment: it's a "mis-feature".   It has always been best practise to use `this.id` within an inline event handler.

Comment: Curiously it still works in Firefox, but not in Safari.

Comment: try to change `id` in `nodeName` and see the value

Answer (score 2):

From here:

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#the-event-handler-processing-algorithm

> ## Scope
>
> **If eventHandler is an element's event handler, then let Scope be NewObjectEnvironment(document, the global environment)**.
>
> Otherwise, eventHandler is a Window object's event handler: let Scope
>   be the global environment.
>
> If form owner is not null, let Scope be NewObjectEnvironment(form
>   owner, Scope).
>
> **If element is not null, let Scope be NewObjectEnvironment(element, Scope)**.

So it seems that the behavior is standard (surpresily, I never do that) so it seems something broken on Chrome.

But, I've tested a simple code on Chrome 71 on Linux and I got the "expected" result.
Maybe you have the structure of HTML broken somewhere and the element is not the current selectbox

Comment: I've tested it on Windows Chrome 71.0.3578 32 bit. The html structure is not broken somewhere.

Comment: @MIrrorMirror, you better make an example which gives incorrect result, for example at jsfiddle.com

Comment: @MIrrorMirror the problem is in this case that the `element` in Chrome is the real element clicked ("OPTION" in this case) that as not an id. The behavior seems not coherent with spec. The proof of work is that you wrap the "Click me" text inside a span element, then you have the same issue

Comment: @LucaRainone hm so the new behaviour in chrome 71 is that if there is an inner element, the onclick of the parent will get its child id instead, unless I specify the scope with this.

Comment: It seems a bug of Chrome 71.

Comment: @LucaRainone what would be the best place to report this? bugs.webkit.org says google has forked it years ago.

Answer (score 1):

According to a quick research, this is a bug in the browser as far as I can tell.

Per the HTML standard [1], such inline handlers should be initialized by the browser using `FunctionCreate`, where the `Scope` is assigned as follows:

> If element is not null, let `Scope` be `NewObjectEnvironment(element, Scope)`.

Let's decipher this by referring to the ECMAScript 2019 language specification [2].
Apparently, a `NewObjectEnvironment(element, Scope)` creates a new Lexical Environment where the initially-defined variable names are taken from the object passed as the first argument - `element`. Think of it as taking all properties of the `element` (an Element object), iterating over them (regardless of whether they are enumerable or not), and putting them into variables named after those properties. The spec describes this as follows:

> Each object Environment Record is associated with an object called its binding object. An object Environment Record binds the set of string identifier names that directly correspond to the property names of its binding object.

Therefore, it seems that the callback that is created from the string in `onclick` should indeed have all properties of your `<select>` Element available **in scope**, including `id`.

References:

1. https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#handler-onclick
2. https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-newobjectenvironment

Answer (score 0):

Parsing data like this is a really old way to do stuff like this and the latest version of Chrome don't support this anymore.

The way to get DOM elements now has to be done like this :

```html
document.querySelector('#myselect');
document.getElementById('myselect');
```

Prefer getting the dom information directly in your .js file than parsing information like this.

Comment: It's still valid to use `this.id` in an inline event handler, even if inline event handlers are themselves considered poor practise these days.

Comment: I'm not sure how what you say is relevant, I'm talking about the onclick event, not getting DOM elements

Comment: I've seen some problems with Chrome when I was working with js. It seems that js elements in html aren't full supported anymore and that it is better to use eventlisteners now

Comment: @TristanVermeesch that's tosh.  Whilst it is indeed better to use event listeners, inline event handlers are still perfectly well supported _if they're written properly_.   An inline event handler just gets wrapped up inside the body of an anonymous function and `this` gets set to the clicked element.   It's relying on "magic" variables that causes problems.

Comment: I must have redt it wrong then. Didn't know `this` was still used in those cases. So the best way will be to use it like you said then, even if of course event listeners are the way of doing it now